Where does someone go with Tzara'as if they are dwelling in a Ir Miklat?
If someone accidentally kills someone and is dwelling in an Ir Miklat and gets tzara'as, where do they go? Do they need to leave the city for 7 days? What if it entails Pikuach Nefesh on this person's part?
According to this post which references the Rambam, it should seem that for everything, he should stay in the Ir Miklat:
Can an unintentional murderer leave Ir Miklat for Shalosh Regalim?

Such a case seems unlikely, since a Metzora only needs to leave the city if it has a wall surrounding it (Mishnah Keilim 1:7) and an Ir Miklat is not allowed to have a wall surrounding it (Gemara Arachin 33b).
Additionally, the murderer may leave the city up until the Techum, which is two thousand cubits outside the city (see Bamidbar 33:5), and a Metzora must seemingly leave only the actual city, and he may remain within the Techum.

This is clever but not precise. "Walled city" here doesn't mean actually has a wall but rather had a wall originally (Arachin 32a). Plausibly even after they knocked down the wall for Ir Miklat it retained it's sanctity

@DoubleAA, that is what I originally thought, but see the first Tosafos to Arachin 34a.

Yes, but 1) metzora doesn't have to have the same din as for leviyim (this is usually discussed in the context of megilla), and 2) Gamla up north is listed as an ir miklat https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37969&st=&pgnum=591 and a walled city https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%98_%D7%95

@DoubleAA, regarding Gamla being a valid Ir Miklat, see Tzoftas Pane'ach on Hilchos Matnas Aniyim 2:9

He seems to hold that it did not actually function as an Ir Miklat, i.e. it wasn't קולט, and it was only selected in order that the other cities should be valid.
